# Debugger of SQL Developer exits with ORA-30687 when DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job() is executed

Tags: oracle, debugging, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I debug a PL/SQL procedure with the debugger of Oracle's SQL Developer, the debugger exits when it passes a DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job(). The error is: `ORA-30687: session terminated by debugger`.

According to the logs the job was executed successfully. Furthermore, debugging works fine when I step through ordinary PL/SQL code. I don't know why the debugger exits when the job is run. The job executes an external Java application. Here is the setup:

```sql
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
  job_name => job_name1,
  job_type => 'EXECUTABLE',
  job_action => 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe',
  job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
  comments => 'Job to call batch script on Windows',
  auto_drop => FALSE,
  number_of_arguments => 5,
  enabled => FALSE
);

-- setting job arguments...
DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job(job_name1);
-- The debugger exits on the statement above and does not reach the following lines...
```

Any ideas?

Used software:

- SQL Developer 20.4.0.379 (Host: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)
- Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition 19.0.0.0.0 (Host: Windows Server 2016)

Comment: what are you actually wanting to debug? you can't debug CREATE_JOB(), it's wrapped plsql

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I want to debug my custom PL/SQL procedure, not the job. Unfortunately, the debugger exits when it reaches DBMS_SCHEDULER.run_job() so that I cannot debug the code after this call.

Comment: interesting...are you stepping over or stepping into? not that it should matter, what version oracle db and SQLDev are you using?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I just added the versions to the end of the question. And I'm just stepping over or executing the code and waiting for breakpoint to trigger (after the job_run).

Comment: Since dbms_scheduler is wrapped, I'm pretty sure that's why you can't do a full trace...